# Alfa AWUS036ACM USB WiFi Adapter and Windows Server 2019/2022 support

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, usb

I am thinking of buying **Alfa AWUS036ACM** USB WiFi Adapter for using it in my home lab for Kali (VM) and Windows Server 2019/2022 (VM).

This adapter is based on the **MediaTeck MT7612U** chipset.

I know that Kali and many other Linux distributions support it natively (kernel).

But what about Windows Server 2019/2022 support, I can't find any information on this subject.

Comment: Windows Server 2019 and 2022 are based on their respective versions of the Windows 10 kernel. Drivers that support Windows 10 work on those versions of Windows Server. It’s rare drivers are released that only support Windows Server and not Windows 10. Windows 10 drivers exist for that device. I haven’t done any research beyond the fact they exist. So it’s possible although extremely unlikely they don’t support newer versions of Windows 10.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not always true. I have tried Realtek based usb adapters and they worked with windows10/11 but not with servers. Microsoft have some restrictions on what is supported by their server releases.

Comment: You should submit an answer so it can be upvoted instead of providing an answer within the body of your question

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested it on Windows Server 2022 (Virtualbox VM, USB passthrough) and can confirm that it works with the Mediatek driver https://files.alfa.com.tw/?dir=%5B1%5D%20WiFi%20USB%20adapter/AWUS036ACM/Windows (digital signer: Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher)

Ironically, it didn't work in VirtualBox with Ubuntu and Kali. But it worked on Proxmox/Kali VM right away, though.

UPDATE:
It works now with Kali in Virtualbox.
The solution:

1. Before starting a Kali VM, disconnect a wifi adapter from the host.
2. Only after Kali is loaded, connect it back. And do not forget to create a USB filter for the wifi adapter (listed as a chipset).